# Add POST body with IIS web.config rewrite

Tags: iis, web-config, arr

I'm using IIS as a reverse proxy to avoid CORS issues for data fetching. I'd like to store auth data (client id and secret) in the web.config and create a request body that gets included with the matching request. Is this possible? If not, is it possible to add that info to a header?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        ...
        <rule name="proxyRule" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://dataserver/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You need to send a authentication request from the client. IIS is just a container hosted.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ? im facing the same issue

Comment: @ishaym unfortunately, not. sorry